# @Autowired service from Spring Boot is null in WAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, swagger

first of all I apologize for the inconvenience, I make this consultation because I have spent days with this problem and I do not find the right solution. I have a project called fact-electronica-api designed using swagger codegen, through this I have the paths to perform REST calles. Once the user makes a call of this type the api project communicates with another project that has the core which use Spring Boot and performs the query with the database. The problem I have is that when I make from the api an autowired to the service defined in the core this is null.

Excuse my English, I am from Uruguay, I hope you understand the problem I am facing.For further understanding, I have attached images.

- Fact electronica Api

[image]

- Factelec-core

[image]

Service through which I receive the rest call and communicate with the core.

[image]

Service in core

[image]

Dependence on the api to the core

[image]

Spring Boot initializer, when you start the ear in wildfly, this project starts automatically and makes the relevant settings.

[image]

I would be grateful if someone could guide me in solving this problem, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the help that was given to me by Nurio Fernández and Andrei Kovrov i was able to find out the right way to accomplish what i wanted to do.

First of all I integrate Spring into the api, and not only into the core, moving spring boot from the core to the api, resulting in this class in the api.

> Api - ApplicationInitializer.java

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.factelcore.*","uy.com.antel.fact.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.factelcore.repository")
public class ApplicationInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationInitializer.class,args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }
 
    private static Class<ApplicationInitializer> applicationClass = ApplicationInitializer.class;
    
}
```

By doing this I made sure I had a spring context in the api, which I could work with. When I start Spring from here I scan all the api and core files, performing the appropriate configuration of the beans.

After doing this, I needed to capture the context to recover the beans that are defined in the core, so I could work with the @Service class defined in the core. For this I created the following class:

> Api - AppContextUtil.java

```
@Component
public class AppContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    
    @Autowired 
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private static ApplicationContext appContext;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (context != null) {
            setApplicationContext(context);         
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        AppContextUtil.appContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return appContext;
    }
}
```

Once this was done, using the SolicitudApiServiceImpl I was able to do the following to invoke the bean I needed at a certain time:

Api - SolicitudApiServiceImpl.java

```
ApplicationContext cont = AppContextUtil.getContext();
SolicitudInformacionService solInfServ = cont.getBean(SolicitudInformacionService.class);
```

I don't know if this is the ideal way to do this, but in my case it worked for me, if there is someone who has a better way to do it feel free to tell me so I can improve the code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `SolicitudApiServicelmpl` isn't a Spring bean, so Spring wouldn't consider all class's fields annotated with `@Auowired` for dependency injection. Try to annotate this class as `@Service` to add the class's instance to Spring context or create a factory for
`SolicitudApiServicelmpl` which generates Spring proxy instead of a simple object.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for responding. Try using the annotation @Service but it still doesn't detect it, can you give me a little more help?

Comment: Your `SolicitudApiServicelmpl` is annotated with `@RequestScoped`. I'm not an expert in JEE but I can assume the object lifetime is the *per request*. . Moreover, it's not an object it's a proxy (probably JDK one). What's the purpose you annotated the service with this annotation?

Comment: Yes, it has that notation, but to prove what you suggested I took it out. In fact that annotation is inserted by swagger when the server stub is created, I have doubted if I leave it or take it out.

Comment: Does it work with `@Service` and without `@RequestScoped` at the same time?

Comment: No, I debug it and solInfServ is null.

Comment: I could simply mix the api project with the core and everything would fall into Spring, but that's not the idea. I wanted to have abstraction between the api and the core. The api does not work directly with spring, it is the core that does, the only function that the api fulfills is communication.

Comment: You need to figure out why the class is absent in your Spring context. That's the key. Without seeing the code, it's hard to help you. Also, try to instantiate a bean without annotations like `@Service` and etc you just need to add it in your Spring configuration with `@Bean` annotation

Comment: To make it easier, I created a Git repository so you can view the code. At the end of the post you can see the link. Does it impact my adding @Service to the Api if the core doesn't have a dependency on it?

Comment: I can't run your code because a lot of dependencies are absent. I can only suggest you try to figure out the root cause (I described above how) or hire someone to resolve your issue.

Comment: It is not my intention that you run the code, I thought that it would be easier for you to visualize the problem if you saw the code of the projects. I'm going to keep trying, but the core doesn't know the api, so I can't create a dependency in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating `SolicitudApiServicelmpl` spring instance.

Spring context (witch makes `@Autowired` work) needs you to create that instance thought to Spring and not with a java native `new SolicitudApiServicelmpl()`.

You can create that instance with a lot of techniques, here you have some of them:

## Static context with "manual wired" (not recommended)

```java
public class Main {

   private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      context = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
   }

   public static ConfigurableApplicationContext getContext() {
      return context;
   }

}
```

```java
public class SolicitudApiServicelmpl {

   private ConfigurableApplicationContext context = Main.getContext();

   private SolicitudInformacionService solInfServ = context.getBean(SolicitudInformacionService.class);

   // Now `solInfServ` is not null anymore.
   // ...
}
```

## Creating a SolicitudApiServicelmpl instance within the Spring context

```java
@Component
public class SomeClassWithSpringContext {

   @Autowired private SolicitudApiServicelmpl solicitudService;
   // with this @Autowired should work in the `service` instance.

}
```

or with the context instance:

```java
@Component
public class SomeClassWithSpringContext {

   @Autowired private WebApplicationContext context;

   public void someMethodOrSomewhere() {
      SolicitudApiServicelmpl service = context.getBean(SolicitudApiServicelmpl.class);
      // with this @Autowired should work in the `service` instance.
   }

}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for responding, I tried both solutions.The second one, the one of the instance, as the core doesn't have a dependency on the api I can't import the class SolicitudApiServicelmpl. And in the first one, for some reason the context is null. Could it be because core extends to SpringBootServletInitializer?